# Cross-compiling Rust project for Cortex-M4 in Windows

Tags: windows, rust, arm, embedded, cortex-m

I'm having a hard time cross-compiling an embedded Rust project for Cortex-M4 in Windows. Going through the [Embedded Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/embedded-book/intro/install.html), I understood that it is needed to install the necessary target and toolchain. I'm trying to do this as follows (in a Windows cmd session):

```
> rustup target add thumbv7em-none-eabihf
info: component 'rust-std' for target 'thumbv7em-none-eabihf' is up to date

> rustup toolchain install stable-thumbv7em-none-eabihf
info: syncing channel updates for 'stable-thumbv7em-none-eabihf'
info: latest update on 2021-05-10, rust version 1.52.1 (9bc8c42bb 2021-05-09)
error: target 'thumbv7em-none-eabihf' not found in channel.  Perhaps check https://doc.rust- 
lang.org/nightly/rustc/platform-support.html for available targets
```

I do not understand the above error message. I have checked the provided link, and it seems that cortex-m4 is a "tier 2" target. I am suspicious that I have used the wrong toolchain prefix, e.g. "stable"?

Of course, if I skip the above and try to build the project with `cargo build`, it fails while looking for the wrong linker executable, i.e.:

```
error: linker `link.exe` not found
  |
  = note: The system cannot find the file specified. (os error 2)

note: the msvc targets depend on the msvc linker but `link.exe` was not found

note: please ensure that VS 2013, VS 2015, VS 2017 or VS 2019 was installed with the Visual C++ option
```

As a side note, the project builds fine on Linux and Macos.

Could someone shed some light on how to set up the toolchain and target correctly? Unfortunately, the Embedded Rust book does not dive into OS-specific toolchain installation.

Comment: if it works on other operating systems this sounds like a tech support ticket for the rust folks or whomever wrote the tutorial or maintains the github files/sources

Comment: what did they say when you asked them about it?